# Logical OR in regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to test using java regex the following cases:

- AB -> allowed
- AC -> allowed
- ABC -> allowed
- A -> forbidden

Here are the A, B and C regex:

- A: `(([0-9]{1,3})(\.[0-9]{1,3})?)`
- B: `(\+([0-1](\.[0-9]{1,3}))`
- C: `(-([0-1](\.[0-9]{1,3}))`

So how can I create my regex using a logical OR?

**Solution**

```
^(([0-9]{1,3})(\.[0-9]{1,3})?)([-+]([0-1](\.[0-9]{1,3}))|(\+([0-1](\.[0-9]{1,3}))(\-([0-1](\.[0-9]{1,3})))))$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the `B` and `C` regexes with putting `+` and `-` within a character class and use the following regex :

```
^(([0-9]{1,3})(\.[0-9]{1,3})?)([-+]([0-1](\.[0-9]{1,3}))|(\+([0-1](\.[0-9]{1,3}‌​))(\-([0-1](\.[0-9]{1,3})))))$
```

In this case always you will have `A` and after it there is `B` or `C` or `BC`

Explain :

Your regex will be `AB` or `AC` or `ABC` so after `A` you want `B` or `C` or `BC` you can create the `B`or`C` with putting `+` and `-` within a character class:

```
([-+]([0-1](\.[0-9]{1,3}))
```

And then use pip (`|`) as a logical or between the preceding option and `BC` that is the following :

```
(\+([0-1](\.[0-9]{1,3}))(\-([0-1](\.[0-9]{1,3}))
```

Comment: the order is important when the string uses both, + is first - is second

Comment: @Athanor So if you find this answer helpful you can tell this to community by voting and accepting the answer ;)

Comment: I'm testing, you'll get the feedback ASAP (I've parenthesis problems...)

Comment: Your solution works, here is the regex with missing parenthesis: `^(([0-9]{1,3})(\.[0-9]{1,3})?)([-+]([0-1](\.[0-9]{1,3}))|(\+([0-1](\.[0-9]{1,3}))(\-([0-1](\.[0-9]{1,3})))))$`

Answer (score 1):

Several solutions:

1. Write it as you say it: `AB|AC|ABC`
2. Avoid redundancy: `A(BC?|C)` or `A(B?C|B)`

Answer (score 0):

Use three patterns separated by `|` operator. To match `AB` or `AC`, just put `B` or `C` inside a non-capturing group with both patterns are separated by alternation operator.

```
(([0-9]{1,3})(\.[0-9]{1,3})?)(\+([0-1](\.[0-9]{1,3}))(-([0-1](\.[0-9]{1,3}))|(([0-9]{1,3})(\.[0-9]{1,3})?)(?:(\+([0-1](\.[0-9]{1,3}))|(-([0-1](\.[0-9]{1,3})))
|<-----------------------------------ABC----------------------------------->|<------------AB or AC----------------------------------------------------------->
```